# Symfony 2, accees entities object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, symfony

it's my first post.
i create web application in Symfony 2 ( new for me )

```
Class Statistique
 id         //int
 userId     //int
 ladate     //date
 scores     //int
```

i send my entities to the Twig.

{{entities}}

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
object(Did\MembresBundle\Entity\Statistique)[420]
private 'id' => int 1
private 'userId' => int 1
private 'ladate' => 
object(DateTime)[418]
public 'date' => string '2015-03-26 00:00:00' (length=19)
public 'timezone_type' => int 3
public 'timezone' => string 'Europe/Paris' (length=12)
private 'scores' => int 18
```

it's mean Users 1 make scores:18 the 2015/03/26 ( It's OK)

I would like to create chart with entities of course I have more than 1 data in statistique i put only one for use in StackOverflow

How can i access entities in Javascript ?

I would like to use Google Chart with entities, it's easy to use Google Chart, i put random data it's ok, but i need to access entities, to put it in chart.

i tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tabstat = {{entities|json_encode|raw}};        
    alert(tabstat[0].scores); // give me Undefined
    alert(tabstat);//give me [object Object ]
</script>
```

what's wrong with this ?

copy past code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var tabstat = [{}];        
    alert(tabstat[0]);
    alert(tabstat);
</script>
```

Comment: What is it rendered into? Show us the plain JS.

Comment: Okay. How can we help you with that if you don't provide the pure JS? Just open the rendered page body and copy-paste the corresponding piece of JS here.

Comment: alert(tabstat[0].scores); Must give me 18 they give me nothing why ?

Comment: Please provide the pure JS from the rendered page (not sure why I have to repeat it 3 times).

Comment: You open the page source, you select the code, you press `Ctrl+C`, you edit your question and paste using `Ctrl+V`. Are you seriously having problems with copying a 535 characters long string? Like, it's not a joke?

Comment: And it's still not JS. Please right click on the page and select "View page source", then copy the **raw JS code**. We need JS, not php, not twig template, but JS.

Comment: `var tabstat = [{}];` --- so, it's empty. The answer for why it's `undefined` is: the object is empty.

Comment: {{dump(entities)}} give me data it's not empty, what's happen ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.jsonserializable.php  `json_encode` has no idea how to serialize your objects. Also check http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: can i do it, without json_encode ?

Comment: You can: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/serializer.html + http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to serialize your entities first in your controller :

http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

pass them to your twig after that as array of formated json.